Probable culprit: CPU vs mainboard
Such entries in syslog I have noticed:
mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Ran a memtest86 with 1.5 passes OK on Core 0. Reran it with SMP support (parallel core usage of the two cores this CPU has) and it froze with a status line of /W. Which made me assume there is perhaps a problem with Core 0 only.
Booted with kernel option isolcpus=0 -> same behaviour, i.e. PC would freeze while booting or shortly after. Same mce entry lines (two lines early at boot) in syslog.
Then booted with kernel option isolcpus=1 -> this gets the PC to boot and run fine... until I put some stress on the CPU, when it freezes again. The mce entries have now gone away.
No matter which cores are selected, there are no other relevant entries in syslog prior to the freezes.
rasdaemon is not easily installable on the PC in case it helps with anything.
Another bit of weirdness: ever since I have owned this PC, it would, at times upon an OS graceful reset, turn off for a few seconds then turn back on. I think the OS quits cleanly and only at the hardware reset does it sometimes do that. PSU is new and it has already done it once.
edit
Or maybe is the mainboard... is this output definite ?
Was checking for a thermal issue with Core 1 under heavy load
kellogs@q4os-desktop:~/gqrx/build$ sensors
atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:       +1.26 V  (min =  +0.80 V, max =  +1.60 V)
 *+3.3 Voltage:       +2.85 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)*
 +5 Voltage:         +4.82 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
 +12 Voltage:       +13.72 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU FAN Speed:      1654 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
CHASSIS1 FAN Speed:    0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
CHASSIS2 FAN Speed:    0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
POWER FAN Speed:       0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
*CPU Temperature:    +429496728.6°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)*
MB Temperature:      +29.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +44.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +38.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)


Yet rasdaemon or other way to retrieve the MCE log (IPMI BMC log, for instance) is the key to solve the problem. If you are allowed to even reboot the system, you can create a live system with rasdaemon and boot into it, then trigger the problem and evaluate what's happening.

CPU temp looks a tad on the high side. ;-)
I'd investigate a BIOS/UEFI update.

Can you please provide a clear summary of the problems you are having? reading you question it just seems like you saw a message in the logs. there will always be log entries regarding hardware that don't actually cause any impact to the user, so don't be distracted by them unless they seem responsive on an actuall issue you are having. second, i don't think i've ever actually had a CPU fail, or if it did, it did so along with the mobo. I have had some motherboard/ram issues however. most things that could damage a CPU will damage a mobo as well. thats my take on it anyway.
